# Mypipes module install in python

Tags: python

I am a student of Data Analyst. I am using Jupyter notebook and trying to run the code `from mypipes import *`.

It was getting an error message :

> No module named 'mypipes'.

So I tried to install the module in the Terminal. I was getting the error as

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypipes (from versions: none).

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: How did you try to install mypipes? What command did you use?

Comment: Could you point us to a webpage with more information about mypipes? Because I can't find it on PyPI.

Comment: I used the command "pip install mypipes" It shows the the error: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mypipes (from versions: none)"

No matching distribution found for mypipes

I am in Anaconda Prompt. I am not sure is the right way. Please guide me through. I am new to it.

Comment: [PyPI is where pip search for `mypipes`](https://pypi.org/search/?q=mypipes); I don't see anything like that, and likely neither does pip. Again, please point us to some webpage or similar that contains anything about mypipes, because I don't know what it is, and I can't find it.

Comment: Although you need to use `pip` when there is no conda recipe , in general because you mention the Anaconda prompt, keep in mind that Anaconda/conda is your primary package manager and you should endeavor to install things with it because of that. That isn't meant for you specific problem; however, keep it in mind. ....About your actual issue here...Here I suspect you have a file named `mypipes.py`? (Or are supposed to have because that isn't a package at PyPI.) You are probably supposed to put that in the same directory as your Jupyter notebook file and then run `from mypipes import *`.